# Integrate Google Protocol Buffers with Xcode project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, protocol-buffers

I already have generated `.h` and `.m` files for classes in Objective-C in project. With the reference to [official tutorial](https://github.com/google/protobuf/tree/master/objectivec#building) I add `objectivec/\*.h` & `objectivec/GPBProtocolBuffers.m` to my project. But there are many errors after that. How correctly include the runtime sources in project? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may add the `include path` of **Google Protocol Buffer** in Xcode's `User Header Search Path`.

[image]